# Refresh browser cache on opening it

Tags: jquery, django, firefox, nginx

I have a webpage which use jquery.ajax to perform some actions. When I call ajax action, close browser and then open it I don't see changes made by ajax. How can I force browser to refresh page on opening?

Comment: Are your "ajax actions" called manually, or on `document.ready()`?

Comment: So when you refresh the page you need to make the ajax call again for it to take effect.  Or am I misunderstanding something?  A page refresh will only show it as it is in the source.

Comment: to force browser to refresh `location.reload();`

Comment: I don't have to make call again. Refresh is enough. The problem is that when I open firefox it looks like the page is loaded from cache and no request to server is performed.

Comment: If I will call reload on opening page don't I get infinite loop?

Comment: Put the ajax call in a `document.ready` handler instead of calling it manually.  It will then be called when the page is loaded.

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to join presented solutions. `location.reload()` only will not work, because browser will reload page infinitely.

Try to make ajax call to webserver on document.ready() which will check only if something on page has changed. Confront it with current page content and refresh if needed. You will need `cache` parameter in your ajax call. Without it call will return its previous state.

Answer (score 3):

add this to the `<head>` segment:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
```

that should force your browser to reload the page every time you load it

Here is something to prevent ajax from being cached:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    cache: false
}).done(function( html ) {
    $("#results").append(html);
});
```

Comment: Does that also force ajax calls to not be cached?  I don't think it does.

Comment: for that you can just set some flag in jquery to stop ajax from caching